# Popup Dialog as Menu when Menu is clicked

Tags: android, menu, dialog

I want to implement Dialog where I will be able to set values. [image: Something like this]

I also would want to Dialog will Popup when I click on three dots (Menu) on Toolbar. [image: I've got toolbar like this]

So far I've got menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>


<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_allclients_min_date"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="@string/menu_min_date"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_allclients_max_date"
    android:orderInCategory="201"
    android:title="@string/menu_max_date"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_allclients_min_amount"
    android:orderInCategory="202"
    android:title="@string/menu_min_amount"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_allclients_max_amount"
    android:orderInCategory="203"
    android:title="@string/menu_max_amount"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Now, when Menu is clicked it show as list of four items. But It isn't a way I want to implement it.

I would also know is there any listener when Menu icon( three dots ) is clicked. It would solve my problem.

Comment: override methods for onCreateOptionsMenu() and onOptionsItemSelected(), inflate the menu on the first method (onCreateOptionsMenu) and check for the id of the menu clicked on the method onOptionsItemSelected() when user selects an option then call method which implements the dialog, you can use a DatePickerDialog and have its listeners get the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For help i sugest, if you dont have more than 2 menu itens, make a menu item set the 3 dots as icon and always as showasaction. After that in on menu item selected in your activity make a switch to check item selected and if is the 3 dots item make the dialog.